# {{input value=someProperty}} defines a property magically? Can i achieve the same with <input {bind-attr value="newTitle"}}>?

Tags: ember.js

So here's this example: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/

```
 {{input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" 
          value=newTitle action="createTodo"}}
```

This helper uses a `newTitle` property. This property is not defined anywhere in JS code, only in the template (in the `{{input}}` helper to be specific). But this property is accessed in JS code:

```
Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
      // Get the todo title set by the "New Todo" text field
      var title = this.get('newTitle');
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

I decided to add an additional action on this input. But the `{{input}}` helper does not seem to accept additional actions. So i decided to replace it with its HTML alternative:

```
<input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" 
          value=newTitle {{action createTodo}}>
```

I haven't added an additional action yet. But this change resulted in `createTodo` action failing! The `this.get('newTitle')` getter returns `undefined`.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/ImukUZO/205/edit Please follow the steps outlined there to see the issue in action.

The questions are:

1. Does the `{{input value=newTitle action="createTodo"}}` heplper do some magic that `<input value=newTitle {{action createTodo}}>` does not do? Creates the `newTitle` property?
2. Where is this difference documented? Please provide a link.
3. Where is the 'newTitle' property created on? Route? View? Controller? Model?
4. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with `<input value=newTitle {{action createTodo}}>` without explicitly defining the `newTitle` property in JS (just like it is possible with `{{input value=newTitle action="createTodo"}}`)?

Bonus question 5: How do i hook extra events to the `{{input}}` helper? For example, i can do `<input {{action foo}} {{action bar on="mouseEnter"}}>`, how do i do the same with `{{input}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the {{input value=newTitle action="createTodo"}} heplper do some
>   magic that  does not do?
>   Creates the newTitle property?

The input helper (in this case) is basically syntax sugar for `{{view Ember.TextField value=someProperty}}`. This is not the same as `<input {{bind-attr value="someProperty"}}>` as bind-attr is only one-way (data -> dom). Ember.TextField includes the [TextSupport Mixin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L29-L37) which observes relevant events to make the binding two way

> Where is this difference documented? Please provide a link.

I don't know. I suspect all the examples in the docs use the input helper instead of bind-attr, for this exact reason.

> Where is the 'newTitle' property created on? Route? View? Controller? Model?

When you "create" a property by binding to a property that doesn't exist yet, it will always be created on the current context. To see the current context put {{this}} in your template (or {{log this}} or {{debugger}} - which pauses with "this" being set to the context). This is *usually* the controller.

> Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with  without explicitly defining the newTitle property in JS (just like it is possible with {{input value=newTitle action="createTodo"}})?

No, to have two way binding to inputs you need to use the input helper or Em.TextField or a subclass.